# Probability related to games

Tags: probability

Two men $A$ and $B$, play a match consisting of separate games. The probability of $A$ winning a game being $p$ and the probability of $B$ winning a game is $q$ ( $p+ q$ is not necessarily equal to $1$) They start the match with $n$ counters each and the winner of each game receives a counter from loser; the first player to win all $2n$ counters wins the match. If the probability that, when $A$ has $k$ counters he will eventually win the match, is denoted by $u(k)$, prove that $(p+q)u(k) = p u(k+1) + q u((k-1)$.
What is the initial probability that $A$ will win the match?

By rearranging the recursive formula you can obtain,
p{ u(k) - u(k+1) } = q { u(k-1) - u(k) }
Now if you substitute k = 1,2....,2n-1 and add all equations,
p u(1) + q u( 2n-1) = p
Is there any possibility to go ahead with this and find u(n) ?

Edited
After discussing this issue with @Ivan and friends in other communities I thought better way is to use the roots 1 , q/p  of the quadratic equation px^2 - (p+q)x + q = 0 to obtain the general solution of u(k) and I suggested it as  λ + μ ( q/p)^k in my comments. If k = 0 there is no chance of winning for A therefore u(0) = 0 . If k = 2n definitely A wins therefore u(2n) = 1
Using these informations constants λ, μ can be obtained and formula for u(k) can be derived.
Here I have another suggestion, that is how can you verify the result obtained for u(n) by considering n=1 case.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Does $1-(p+q)$ represent the probability of a tie and in this case no counter is exchanged? At any rate, you need to analyse the first game and then use the "renewal argument." Once the first game passed, you have new initial conditions, the same process and everything stochastic should then be the same.

Comment: @ William,  yes I also think probability 1- ( p+q) is for a draw .

Comment: Let $A$ starts some separate game with $k$ counters $1\leq k \leq 2n-1$, then after this game $A$ has $k$ counters with probability $1-p-q$, $k+1$ counters with probability $p$ and $k-1$ counters with probability $q$. Then $u(k)=(1-p-q)u(k)+pu(k+1)+qu(k-1)$, which immediately transforms to your equation.

Comment: @ Ivan- I think your suggestion may be ok .

Comment: @Ivan - What about explicit formula for u(k) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ starts some separate game with $k$ counters $1≤k≤2n−1$, then after this game $A$ has $k$ counters with probability $1−p−q$, $k+1$ counters with probability $p$ and $k−1$ counters with probability $q$. Then $$u(k)=(1−p−q)u(k)+pu(k+1)+qu(k−1)\Rightarrow (p+q)u(k)=pu(k+1)+qu(k−1)$$

**Edit:** I've made misprint starting from this point. Below is new version.

$$u(k+1)=\frac{p+q}{p}u(k)-\frac{q}{p}u(k-1)=au(k)+bu(k-1), 1\leq k \leq 2n-1$$

$$a=\frac{p+q}{p}, b=-\frac{q}{p}$$

Let $u(1)=x$, then we can solve recurrence $u(k+1)=au(k)+bu(k-1)$ with initial conditions $u(0)=0$, $u(1)=x$:

$$\lambda^2=a\lambda+b\Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{a}{2}\pm\sqrt{b+\frac{a^2}{4}}$$

$$a=\frac{p+q}{p}, b=-\frac{q}{p}\Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{p+q\pm|p-q|}{2p}$$

$$\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=\frac{q}{p}$$

$$u(k)=A\lambda_1^k+B\lambda_2^k$$

$$u(0)=0, u(1)=x \Rightarrow A+B=0, A\lambda_1+B\lambda_2=x\Rightarrow\\
B=-A, A(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)=x \Rightarrow A=\frac{x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}, B=-\frac{x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$$

$$u(k)=A\lambda_1^k+B\lambda_2^k=\frac{x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(\lambda_1^k-\lambda_2^k)$$

$$u(2n)=1 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(\lambda_1^{2n}-\lambda_2^{2n})=1\Rightarrow x=\frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{\lambda_1^{2n}-\lambda_2^{2n}}$$

$$u(k)=\frac{x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(\lambda_1^k-\lambda_2^k)=\frac{\lambda_1^{k}-\lambda_2^{k}}{\lambda_1^{2n}-\lambda_2^{2n}}$$

$$\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=\frac{q}{p}\Rightarrow u(k)=\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^k}{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{2n}}$$

$$u(n)=\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^n}{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{2n}}=\frac1{1+\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^n}=\frac{p^n}{p^n+q^n}$$

Comment: Can we use roots of the quadratic equation px^2 - (p+q)x + q = 0 to write u_k as A + B ( q/p)^k ?

Comment: $u_k=A_1 x_1^k + A_2 x_2^k$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of this quadratic equation ($\lambda_{1,2}$ in the answer). The reason behind it: we seek solution of recurrence in form $u(k)=A x^k$, then if we put this form into recurrence we get quadratic equation $px^2-(p+q)x+q$. Both $x_1$ and $x_2$ give solution in form $u(k)=A x^k$ and general solution is their sum. Then we use boundary conditions $u(0)=0$, $u(2n)=1$ to find coefficients.

Comment: @  Ivan  - you meant u(k) = A + B ( q/p)^k  is the general form, because roots are 1, q/p and most importantly u(k) must be in the interval [ 0,1] ?

Comment: You're right, I've made misprint in beginning part of answer. Answer has more simple form. I've edited answer.

Comment: @ Ivan thank you very much for your assistance to solve this problem.